# Does R's drop1 account for the non-interaction terms when there are both interaction terms and non-interaction terms in the model?

Tags: r, interaction

My question is in the title. I am unsure if the non-interaction terms are being accounted for as the output of drop1 does not include them, but only the interaction terms. The code and output is as follows:

```
> temp = lm(auto.mpg.data$mpg ~ auto.mpg.data$weight + auto.mpg.data$model_year + auto.mpg.data$origin + auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$model_year + auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$origin + auto.mpg.data$model_year:auto.mpg.data$origin)
> drop1(temp, test="F")
Single term deletions

Model:
auto.mpg.data$mpg ~ auto.mpg.data$weight + auto.mpg.data$model_year + 
        auto.mpg.data$origin + auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$model_year + 
    auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$origin + auto.mpg.data$model_year:auto.mpg.data$origin
                                              Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC F value    Pr(>F)    
<none>                                                     3769.8 908.83                      
auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$model_year  1   300.625 4070.4 937.37 31.1807 4.407e-08 ***
auto.mpg.data$weight:auto.mpg.data$origin      1    94.557 3864.3 916.69  9.8074  0.001869 ** 
auto.mpg.data$model_year:auto.mpg.data$origin  1     0.027 3769.8 906.83  0.0028  0.958085    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 `enter code here`
```

Comment: A word of advice, don't use `data$column` when creating formula for linear models. Use `lm(mpg~(weight+model_year+origin)^2, data = auto.mpg.data)` to get the same model.

Comment: It is worth reading http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "account for". `drop1` is just dropping each term and comparing the model without it to the full model.

Comment: What I meant by "account for" is that the singleton terms, weight/model_year/origin, don't seem to get dropped as they don't have their own line in the output. Each of the interaction terms, are dropped and "accounted for" in the output.

Thank you mnel for your helpful advice and link. I found the answer there:
The second option for drop1 is called scope where you can specify with a formula which terms are to be considered for the adding and dropping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `drop1` functions accounts for the lower-level terms if an interaction is present. If a predictor is part of an interaction, it will not be dropped.